# Avro schema: how to create a maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, schema, avro

I'm working on different Spring Boot projects with avro schema generated sources.

I would like to be able to share those avro schemas through different projects.

Is it possible to create a maven dependency for sharing the schemas? if yes, how is it done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maven can hold binary files, yes.

You can use the assembly plugin or [Spf4j Avro](http://www.spf4j.org/spf4j-avro-components/maven-avro-schema-plugin/index.html), for example, to package and distribute the schema files

Or you can compile any generated classes, package into a JAR, then publish that like any other dependency

Comment: This might help https://github.com/zolyfarkas/avro-schema-examples